# How to make sure Flutter Widget refresh/rebuild on bloc state change

Tags: flutter, bloc

I have two Stateful widgets: RecordsFeed and RecordDetails. I also have FetchRecordsBloc to manage data fetching from the backend, with two methods - FetchRecords and ResetRecords.

Desired behaviour is that if a new database record is created successfully on RecordDetails screen, I want to redirect user to RecordsFeed where a new entry will be also displayed (entries are displayed there with reverse order based on timestamp, so the latest record will be on top).

Now, I decided that the simplest way to implement this would be to just reset state of FetchRecordsBloc immediately after creating new record so I add ResetRecords event from RecordDetails widget.

Now the problem I encountered with this approach is that while FetchRecordsBloc is correctly reset and new query to database succeeds, so new state is good basically, but when I navigate to RecordsFeed screen, the ListView behind BlocBuilder is not rebuilt.

After some investigation I think that the issue might be more related to navigation and I tried to call setState on a callback of push (see the code for RecordsFeed widget), but it seemingly doesn't work. When I refresh the page using RefreshIndicator pull action, indeed widget is rebuilt and new record is displayed on top along with the rest.

Could you please suggest how I can make sure that RecordsFeed / BlocBuilder will rebuild when displayed after bloc state is changed from a different screen? Or if I'm doing something stupid here, suggest another way to implement desired behaviour, please? I'm quite new to Flutter and bloc. Thanks a lot.

Few relevant pieces of code:

except from RecordsFeed widget with BlocBuilder:

```dart
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        heroTag: 'createButton',
        onPressed: () {
          if (!isUserLoggedIn) {
            _showSignInDialog();
          } else {
            // TODO setState doesn't work to force a rebuild of the widget :sadface:
            context.push<void>('/records/create').whenComplete(() => setState(() {}));
          }
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        edgeOffset: 100,
        onRefresh: () async {
          if (isUserLoggedIn) {
            context.read<FetchRecordsBloc>().add(RecordsReset());
            // context.read<FetchRecordsBloc>().add(RecordsFetched());
          }
        },
        child: BlocBuilder<FetchRecordsBloc, FetchRecordsState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (!isUserLoggedIn) return const NotSignedInRecordsView();

            switch (state.status) {
              case FetchRecordsStatus.failure:
                return Stack(children: <Widget>[ListView(), const Center(child: Text('failed to fetch posts'))]);
              case FetchRecordsStatus.success:
                if (state.records.isEmpty) {
                  return Stack(children: <Widget>[ListView(), const Center(child: Text('no posts'))]);
                }
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return index >= state.records.length
                        ? const BottomLoader()
                        : RecordTileWithImages(
                            record: state.records[index],
                            onTap: () {
                              context
                                  .push<void>('/records/${state.records[index].id}/view', extra: state.records[index])
                                  .whenComplete(() => setState(() {}));
                            },
                          );
                  },
                  itemCount: state.hasReachedMax ? state.records.length : state.records.length + 1,
                  controller: _scrollController,
                  physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                );
              case FetchRecordsStatus.initial:
              case FetchRecordsStatus.loading:
                return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
```

FetchRecordsBloc:

```dart
class FetchRecordsBloc extends Bloc<FetchRecordsEvent, FetchRecordsState> {
  FetchRecordsBloc() : super(const FetchRecordsState()) {
    on<RecordsFetched>(_onRecordsFetched, transformer: throttleDroppable(AppwriteAPI.apiThrottleDuration));
    on<RecordsReset>(_onRecordsReset);
    add(RecordsFetched());
  }

  final RecordsRepository repository = getIt.get<RecordsRepository>();

  Future<void> _onRecordsReset(RecordsReset event, Emitter<FetchRecordsState> emit) async {
    emit(state.copyWith(
      status: FetchRecordsStatus.initial,
      records: [],
      hasReachedMax: false,
    ));
    add(RecordsFetched());
  }

  Future<void> _onRecordsFetched(RecordsFetched event, Emitter<FetchRecordsState> emit) async {
    final records = await repository.fetchRecordsWithOffset(state.records.length);
    if (records == null) {
      return emit(state.copyWith(status: FetchRecordsStatus.failure));
    } else {
      return emit(state.copyWith(
        status: FetchRecordsStatus.success,
        records: List.of(state.records)..addAll(records),
        hasReachedMax: records.isEmpty,
      ));
    }
  }
}
```

For FetchRecordsState I think I correctly set up Equatable with:

```dart
List<Object> get props => [status, records, hasReachedMax];
```

And this is a fragment of code from RecordsDetails.onSaveRecord function:

```dart
      context.read<CreateRecordBloc>().add(CreateRecordStarted(record: record, mediaGroups: _mediaGroups));
      context.read<FetchRecordsBloc>().add(RecordsReset());
```

I then navigate to RecordsFeed screen via `context.pop<void>();`

RecordsFeed widget and BlocBuilder inside of it are not rebuilt when navigated to after Bloc state update.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with Bloc provider, but i can see that your `ListView` is not re-building. The best way to force it to rebuild is using a `loading` boolean. So you will need to have something like this:

```
   ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
         return loading 
                  ? CircularProgressIndicator
                  : index >= state.records.length....
```

Now in your push navigation you can change the condition to force your listview to rebuild conditionally:

```
   onTap: () {
     setState(() {
       loading = true;
     }
     context.push<void>('/records/${state.records[index].id}/view', extra: state.records[index])
     .whenComplete(() => setState(() {
                         loading = false;
                         }));},
```

It would be best if you store the `loading` variable inside your provider and change the condition before and after changing values inside it